# Boxing a rusqlite Rows iterator

Tags: rust

I am having trouble figuring out how to return an Iterator (`impl` or `Box`) when using `prepare` and `query`.

Here is what I have tried:

```rust
fn foo<'a>(
    conn: &'a mut rusqlite::Connection
) -> Box<impl 'a + fallible_streaming_iterator::FallibleStreamingIterator<Item=rusqlite::Row<'a>>> {
    Box::new(
        conn
            .prepare("SELECT a, b FROM t")
            .unwrap()
            .query(rusqlite::NO_PARAMS)
            .unwrap()
    )
}
```

The problem is the prepared statement is a temporary variable owned by the function scope. (`error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value`).

Comment: The problem is that rusqlite::Rows references the liftime of the Statement which you create by `.prepare()` and then immediately discard. This works if you only keep working with the query rows inside the same function, but not if you try to return it. One solution would be to construct the statement outside the function and pass it in as a parameter.

Comment: If anyone else runs into this problem before someone provides a suitable answer, the `sqlite` crate has a nice `sqlite::Cursor` type that is nice and easy to wrap and provide and iterator for.

Answer (score 2):

> Not possible to return `FallibleStreamingIterator<Item=rusqlite::Row<'a>>` instance from  `foo` function.

**Rust borrow checker will not allow to do that.**

To understand why, we need to understand how `rusqlite::Rows<'a>` is structured.

```rust
/// An handle for the resulting rows of a query.
#[must_use = "Rows is lazy and will do nothing unless consumed"]
pub struct Rows<'stmt> {
    pub(crate) stmt: Option<&'stmt Statement<'stmt>>,
    row: Option<Row<'stmt>>,
}
```

[Github source: Rows](https://github.com/rusqlite/rusqlite/blob/21d0f98f9244ab1dddd93db957c166f1d6eac51a/src/row.rs#L8C1-L13C2)

and it's `FallibleStreamingIterator` implementation looks like

```rust
impl<'stmt> FallibleStreamingIterator for Rows<'stmt> {
    type Error = Error;
    type Item = Row<'stmt>;

    #[inline]
    fn advance(&mut self) -> Result<()> {
    ...
```

[Github source: FallibleStreamingIterator](https://github.com/rusqlite/rusqlite/blob/21d0f98f9244ab1dddd93db957c166f1d6eac51a/src/row.rs#L210C56-L210C56)

`Rows` holds a reference to `Statement`. Let's try to infer lifetime `'stmt` here.

```
      Statement (scope limited to `foo` func)
          |
         Rows (refers Statement so valid scope `foo`)
          |
FallibleStreamingIterator (refers Rows so valid scope `foo`)
```

Possible solution could be

1. either Return owned `rusqlite::Statement<'a>` and query on desired location
2. or Return the computed resultset (owned)